# Как правильно: шпрот или шпротов?

Tags: склонение, грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: *нет **шпрот** на праздничном столе* или *нет **шпротов***?

Answer (score 4):

Смотрим в словарь:

> ШПРО́ТЫ, шпрот и шпро́тов, мн. (ед. шпро́та, -ы, ж. и шпрот, -а, м.).
>
> 1. Мелкая морская промысловая рыба сем. сельдевых.
> 2. мн. ч. (шпро́ты, шпрот и шпро́тов). **Консервы** из этой или другой мелкой рыбы (салаки, кильки и др.).
>
> [Нем. Sprotten]

**Таким образом, правильно и *нет шпрот*, и *нет шпротов*.**

NB! Несмотря на [некоторые свидетельства](https://rg.ru/2006/12/08/koroleva.html) о неправильности *шпротов* в значении консервов, этот вариант фиксируется [авторитетными словарями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C) как равноправный.

Answer (score 1):

**В Нацкорпусе предпочтительной формой является "шпрот"** (мн.ч. Р.п.) (примерно 7:1):

Потом она попросила передать раненым привезённые ею для сына гостинцы и положила на стол **две коробки шпрот**, пакетик конфет. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, ч. 1 (1960)]

На столе бутылка «Рижского бальзама», чекенчик беленькой, горсть копченой ряпушки, второпях, неумело открытая **банка шпротов.** [Виктор Астафьев. Печальный детектив (1982-1985)].

Для сущ. "шпрота" (ж.р.) правильным является только только вариант "нет шпрот", для сущ. "шпрот" (м.р.) возможны оба варианта. Отсюда более употребительным является нулевое окончание.

Answer (score 1):

Рыба - шпрот. Мелкая такая рыбешка семейства сельдевых. Из неё готовили настоящие шпроты, сейчас их практически не осталась.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B_(%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%8B)

Способ приготовления дал название консервам вообще. 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B)
Готовят их обычно из тюльки или салаки.

Так вот, в силу каких-то языковых казусов консервы приобрели женский род. 
Поэтому Марина Королева (см. aer) права, хотя ничего внятного в объяснениях и не предложила.

**Банка шпрот** - это некая консервированная продукция, приготовленная по технологии шпрота. Шпротов (рыбок) в ней почти наверняка нет.

Но при этом **"пять шпротов"** - это пять рыб вида "шпрот европейский" или "шпрот балтийский". В каком контексте это можно употребить при отсутствии этой рыбы как таковой - не знаю.

В словарях часто приводят оба варианта не разделяя по значению. В результате - их смешение и разговоры об ошибках.

Comment: Дак в МАС как раз для консервов дают вариативность, то есть значение как раз разделено.

Comment: Подождите, если вариативность, то это значит, что НЕ разделено ))))

Comment: Посмотрите на приведенную словарную статью, там *четко* для консервов даны варианты.

Comment: Не вижу "приведенной статьи".  Под рукой словаря у меня нет, но я вам верю. ))) *Если для одного понятия "четко" приведены два варианта (которые по логике должны относиться к разным понятиям), значит эти понятия **смешиваются***.

Comment: Вы отказываетесь меня понимать)) Я вас уверяю, что сходил к полке и собственноручно открыл зеленый томик, нашел букву ша — все как у меня в ответе).

Comment: И все-таки для консервов все ясно, но, видно, не всем. Ладно, проехали

Comment: @behemothus  Не это ли и есть та самая синекдохия? Шпроты как содержимое (компонент) консервов подменяют сами консервы. На самом деле если в словаре есть 1, 2, 3... - это разные понятия или разное применение понятия. В некоторых языках одно слово может иметь много таких пунктов.  Рекордсмен на моей памяти - английский look с 22 пунктами.

Comment: @Swift Послушайте, вам обязательно нужно тащить сюда еще один термин? Зачем? Кстати правильная форма - синекдоха. Но я не вижу причин её тут поминать. Камень преткновения - не в этом. В словаре есть два понятия. А ***разделения*** между ними нет. Причем в обоих случаях.